# Why can't I color my black tank top blue by adjusting Hue/Saturation? NOT with Adding a Layer Mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am asking merely about [this Hue/Saturation method](https://youtu.be/1_3CIwlSQwc?t=133) (described [here as Method 2](https://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/photoshop-change-color-of-object/#dt-heading-2-adjust-the-color-using-a-huesaturation-adjustment-layer)) — NOT [the Layer method](https://youtu.be/5h_Il_Ncauo?t=266) (described here as [Add a Layer Mask](https://www.makeuseof.com/photoshop-change-object-color-how-to/)). I know the Hue/Saturation method is worse, [because Hue/Saturation doesn't let you  adjust Lightness independently. If you do, you wash out the shadows.](https://youtu.be/4jG77DO8Jcw?t=269)

[image]

**Question 1.** I picked blue, but why isn't my black halter turning blue?

[image]

I selected the halter correctly, because when I slide Hue/Saturation to the far right, the black halter changes color to dark green!

[image]

#### Questions 2 to 5.

2. What's the purpose of "Color"? If I must adjust "Hue", then why's Color on top? Shouldn't "Hue" be on top?
3. What's the purpose of "Colorize"? What does "Colorize" do? It shouldn't be ticked, correct?
4. What are these 2 color bars? What's their purpose?
5. Rather than clicking on "100%" and typing new percentage — does Photoshop come with a plus and minus option beside the 100%, like other programs? Clicking plus or minus with my mouse is faster for me.

***I know I can switch to the Zoom tool, or hold down my Alt button. I am not asking about these 2 options.***

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you are asking too many unrelated questions, sorry. You should edit to focus on the hue/saturation issue.

Comment: Black has no hue (and same goes for white and gray), which is why the hue slider doesn't do anything. Whatever little the hue slider might do is because it's not 100% grayscale. You could use the "colorize" checkbox to color "grayscale areas", but even then it won't work too well if the color is super black or white, but you can compensate by adjusting the "Lightness" slider towards white in this case. Like halfway between where it's now and the right side (or maybe not even that far). Depending on what you want from the new color, something like 50% gray might be ideal for colorize.

Comment: The problem is because you are trying to adjust the hue of black.  Black is not a colour technically speaking. A gradient map would be my personal choice. Let's you control precisely how the colours are mapped to the black shadows, greys, and highlights. [see example](https://imgur.com/AeR7Ng8)